# possible to get reference assembly address in file for special memory address?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, binary-analysis, memory, processhacker

Hello I try to learn reverse engineering, so i use from `process hacker` to view dynamic strings in the process's memory... ([more info](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11147/21966))

i get something like this :

```
Address  Length Result
-----------------------
0x853978 (43): hello
0xfb5e1a8 (86): hello alex !
```

now i want to know how can i get/find reference address for them ?

I try with `WinHex` but i cant, i don't know how can i do this, is it possible to find reference assembly address in file form memory address (for ex : `0x853978`) or this is not possible in any way.

anyone can help ?

Comment: Binary loaded into memory, relocated and mapped to process' virtual memory. It is vary between static and dynamic addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Process Hacker to find strings, you will look at a running process. Process Hacker iterates over the mapped parts of the processes virtual memory and tries to parse everything it finds as a string.

When you use WinHex to look at your binary, these sections have not been mapped yet and are cramped together into the binary.

tl:dr;

Use another program to check for strings (e.g. exe explorer, pe studio, ida, binaryninja, ...), use a debugger to find the strings at the adresses process hacker tells you, or calculate the file offset utilizing the section information.

Could you clarify what you are trying to do?

**edit**

if you want to find references to strings in code, you are best off utilizing a decent disassembler (binaryninja, radare2, ida pro). It will show you references it can find:

[image]